# Order Automated TFS Builds (Mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, tfs, build, msbuild

I am using TFS 2015 to perform automated builds of my libraries in a cross-platform environment. I just added support for building my libraries on macOS but I am unable to figure out how to order the builds. Here is my situation:

I have libraries A, B, and C (in separate build definitions). Library B depends on library A, and library C depends on library B. Libraries A, B, and C have a small bit of overlap in terms of shared files in TFS, so when a user checks in files from these overlapped directories, all of the libraries are built, but in random order. I need to be able to build library A first, then library B, then library C.

Any help in configuring this (in a way other than creating a single build definition)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature to control the order of vNext build and  move items up / down in the queue.

There is no logical order and without any configuration to control this.

I have created a uservoice for you, you could vote up and monitor it. TFS PM and Admin will kindly review the suggestion.

> **Order TFS vNext Builds**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19960372-order-tfs-vnext-builds

For now you have to use the workaround, creating a new single build definition to combine them.